# Create virtual/fake bridged interface in Debian

Tags: linux, networking, debian, virtual-machine, virtual-network

I have Debian server where I have installed a VM with `libvirt/kvm`
I have created a bridge for it, added the VM to this bridge.

```
224: vm-bridge: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:b7:1f:71:0d:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.0/24 scope global vm-bridge
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This network is routed towards the server on our VPN gateway.

VM has an IP address from this pool `10.0.2.10/24`
I need to create an interface on the server which can be added to the bridge and has an IP address from this pool: `10.0.2.0/24`

How this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding IP address instead of network ID to bridge worked:

```
224: vm-bridge: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:b7:1f:71:0d:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.1/24 scope global vm-bridge
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::30b7:1fff:fe71:d3c/64 scope link
```